# How to convey that two things started at the same time?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, time

If I began eating and drinking at 7am,

can I say:

> I ate my meal, and I drank my liquor from the same time.

Comment: @user3169  NO, my question is different .

Comment: Then you should reference your previous question in this one, and explain what additional information or explanation you need.

Comment: @ user3169   Can I delete that question but retain this question ?

Comment: You can still edit this question so that it is different from the previous one. Then if the question is significantly different, it is possible that it will be reopened. See [**What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions).

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you are looking for is **at the same time**

> I **started** eating and drinking **at the same time**
>   I **started** eating and drinking at 7:00PM

Comment: how do I  express that "I ate my meal, and he drank his  liquor." ?